# Keras: How to concatenate 2 tensors with dynamic shapes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have a use case where I need to concatenate a 2D tensor to a 3D tensor in Keras. The dimensions of the 3D tensor are dynamic (for example, the 3D tensor could be the output of an LSTM layer with shape `[batch_size, num_timesteps, num_features],` where `batch_size` and `num_timesteps` are dynamic).

I have used the `RepeatVector` to repeat the values of the 2D tensor before the "merge" operation with the 3D tensor.

But, in my case, the "merge" operation throws an error (error details below). I've shared below a representative code for the operations I'm trying to achieve, along with the error.

I suspect the problem here is RepeatVector for a dynamic shape. Or, am I missing something more fundamental? Is there a way I can achieve this correctly?

I'm using Keras v2.1.6 with Tensorflow backend v1.8.0.

```
import keras
from keras.layers import *
input_3D = Input(shape=(None,100,), dtype='int32', name='input_3D')
input_2D = Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32', name='input_2D')
input_2D_repeat = RepeatVector(K.shape(input_3D)[1])(input_2D)
merged = merge([input_3D, input_2D_repeat], name="merged", mode='concat')
```

The above code throws below error for the "merge" operation:

> ValueError: "concat" mode can only merge layers with matching output
>   shapes except for the concat axis. Layer shapes: [(None, None, 100),
>   (None, , 100)]

I can see that the second dimension in `input_3D` is `None`, but the second dimension in `input_2D_repeat` is `tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=int32`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

After reading again the question and my answer, I think the solution I posted is not correct. I think you meant to concatenate along the features axis, not the time axis, and also I'm not sure if tensor values like `K.shape(input_3D)[1]` can be used as parameters to a layer like `RepeatVector`. For your case, I think I would probably just resort to a `Lambda` layer to do the whole thing:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
import keras.backend as K

def repeat_and_concatenate(inputs):
    input_3D, input_2D = inputs
    # Repeat 2D vectors
    input_2D_repeat = K.tile(K.expand_dims(input_2D, 1), [1, K.shape(input_3D)[1], 1])
    # Concatenate feature-wise
    return K.concatenate([input_3D, input_2D_repeat], axis=-1)

input_3D = Input(shape=(None,100,), dtype='int32', name='input_3D')
input_2D = Input(shape=(50,), dtype='int32', name='input_2D')
merged = Lambda(repeat_and_concatenate)([input_3D, input_2D])
print(merged)
# Tensor("lambda_1/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, 150), dtype=int32)
```

---

*THE FORMER ANSWER BELOW IS LIKELY WRONG*

You need to specify that you want to concatenate along the "time" axis (instead of the default, which is the last one). You can do this:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import *

input_3D = Input(shape=(None,100,), dtype='int32', name='input_3D')
input_2D = Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32', name='input_2D')
input_2D_repeat = RepeatVector(K.shape(input_3D)[1])(input_2D)
merged = Concatenate(axis=1)([input_3D, input_2D_repeat])
```

Or this:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import *

input_3D = Input(shape=(None,100,), dtype='int32', name='input_3D')
input_2D = Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32', name='input_2D')
input_2D_repeat = RepeatVector(K.shape(input_3D)[1])(input_2D)
merged = concatenate([input_3D, input_2D_repeat], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I realize after reading the solution that I had missed a fundamental thing, i.e., specifying the axis for concat. This solves my problem.

Comment: I was trying a few variations of the above code and I'm hitting the error again. I tried playing with the axis value but no success. Basically, if I change the shape of input_2D to (50,) then the above code fails again. The change I'm trying is "input_2D = Input(shape=(50,), dtype='int32', name='input_2D')".  Can you help?

Comment: @Vinay I think my answer was wrong, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I can see that this works. Can you please explain the line "K.tile(K.expand_dims(input_2D, 1), [1, K.shape(input_3D)[1], 1])". Thanks, again!

Comment: @Vinay Yes, that's pretty much the same as `RepeatVector`, it adds one dimension to have the "time" axis, and then "tiles" (repeats it) over it. It only tiles along the time axis, so the other two axes (batch and features) get a `1` in the `tile` argument.